# Missing Network Settings - "Find Devices and Content"

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, homegroup, private-network

I want to change status of my ethernet connection from public to private. I follwed a tutorial online and found that my windows 10 laptop doesnt have "find devices and content" option. This is a problem [for a lot of people](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/missing-network-settings-find-devices-and-content/bf4a8d57-f0b9-4689-88e8-ab6166ad6691?page=3) it seems. I havent found a solution yet. Any other way to set connection to private would help too. Some of the things i tried are:

[1.) Tried to go to regedit](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/missing-network-settings-find-devices-and-content/bf4a8d57-f0b9-4689-88e8-ab6166ad6691?page=3) and set some value as 1 but couldnt understand what exactly to do.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

PATH: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles`

2.)Turn on network discovery in advanced sharing settings. Didnt work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved: Open "Homegroup" and click on "start the Homegroup troubleshooter" . Skip network troubleshooter and you will get option to convert location to private. Select "Apply this fix" If you have multiple connections then connect one at a time and then troubleshoot.

Comment: Update: Homegroup has been removed since Version 1803, this solution no longer works :(